# MySQL Query Max/Min Field

Tags: mysql

With a query of the format `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` all containing integer values, how can one create a second query based off of this one which has a fourth field which displays the name of the field (`Col1`, `Col2` or `Col3`) which has the highest value for that record, and and fifth which displays the name of the field with the lowest value for the record?

Comment: Ok. How do you think this should be done and what have you done so far?

Comment: perhaps give us some more details, some code?

Comment: I am pretty new to SQL so I don't really know how to approach this. Would an intermediary query be required?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

> With two or more arguments, returns the largest (maximum-valued)
>   argument.

and [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

> With two or more arguments, returns the smallest (minimum-valued)
>   argument.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b963b/2)

Comment: These return the actual values. Is there a similar function to return the name of the columns associated with those values?